# Postgresql - table performance degradation after ANALYZE

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, query-planner

I'm trying to understand this situation: in my test environment (pg14 on debian) I have a table with many rows (18.000.000).
Suppose the table is "**entities**", and in simple terms it has this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE entities (
    id BIGINT not null,
    somefield INTEGER not null,
    otherfield TIMESTAMP not null
);
create index ix1 on entities(somefield);
create index ix2 on entities(otherfield);
```

Then I cloned it twice, say "**entities1**" and "**entities2**" with a dumb script:

```
insert into entities1 select * from entities;
insert into entities2 select * from entities;
```

Then I ran

```
vacuum analyze entities2;
reindex table entities2;
```

and I kept **entities1** untouched.

Now I have this simple query:

```
select extract(year from otherfield), COUNT(*) as n 
from entities1
group by extract(year from otherfield);
```

which results in:

```
2019    43956
2020    5981223
2021    12172333
```

My query runs way faster (2x) in the untouched table than in the analyzed table. 
The execution plans are these:

**entities1**

```
"Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=528695.36..528746.53 rows=200 width=40) (actual time=4774.324..4780.668 rows=3 loops=1)"
"  Group Key: (EXTRACT(year FROM ""otherfield""))"
"  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=528695.36..528742.03 rows=400 width=40) (actual time=4774.316..4780.658 rows=9 loops=1)"
"        Workers Planned: 2"
"        Workers Launched: 2"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=527695.34..527695.84 rows=200 width=40) (actual time=4727.063..4727.064 rows=3 loops=3)"
"              Sort Key: (EXTRACT(year FROM ""otherfield""))"
"              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB"
"              Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB"
"              Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB"
"              ->  Partial HashAggregate  (cost=527685.19..527687.69 rows=200 width=40) (actual time=4727.040..4727.041 rows=3 loops=3)"
"                    Group Key: EXTRACT(year FROM ""otherfield"")"
"                    Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 40kB"
"                    Worker 0:  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 40kB"
"                    Worker 1:  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 40kB"
"                    ->  Parallel Seq Scan on entities1  (cost=0.00..489773.71 rows=7582297 width=32) (actual time=0.548..3302.243 rows=6065837 loops=3)"
"Planning Time: 1.309 ms"
"Execution Time: 4780.718 ms"
```

**entities2**

```
"Gather  (cost=1000.56..4087193.67 rows=16836383 width=40) (actual time=209.129..12448.711 rows=3 loops=1)"
"  Workers Planned: 1"
"  Workers Launched: 1"
"  Single Copy: true"
"  ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.56..2402555.37 rows=16836383 width=40) (actual time=43.676..12263.595 rows=3 loops=1)"
"        Group Key: EXTRACT(year FROM ""otherfield"")"
"        ->  Index Scan using ix2_entities2 on entities2  (cost=0.56..2101113.02 rows=18197512 width=32) (actual time=2.756..9803.865 rows=18197512 loops=1)"
"Planning Time: 0.164 ms"
"Execution Time: 12448.750 ms"
```

what I immediately noticed is that the first plan runs in parallel, so I forced a parallel execution (parallel_setup_cost=100000, parallel_tuple_cost = 0.001) and I obtained this:

```
"GroupAggregate  (cost=1532983.03..2062194.15 rows=16836383 width=40) (actual time=3373.406..10682.438 rows=3 loops=1)"
"  Group Key: (EXTRACT(year FROM ""otherfield""))"
"  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1532983.03..1760751.81 rows=18197512 width=32) (actual time=3352.633..7930.565 rows=18197512 loops=1)"
"        Workers Planned: 2"
"        Workers Launched: 2"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=1432983.00..1451938.74 rows=7582297 width=32) (actual time=3276.100..3999.320 rows=6065837 loops=3)"
"              Sort Key: (EXTRACT(year FROM ""otherfield""))"
"              Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 91728kB"
"              Worker 0:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 88432kB"
"              Worker 1:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 86704kB"
"              ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using ix2_entities2 on entities2  (cost=0.44..385130.71 rows=7582297 width=32) (actual time=1.225..1763.335 rows=6065837 loops=3)"
"                    Heap Fetches: 0"
"Planning Time: 0.124 ms"
"Execution Time: 10693.600 ms"
```

now, with both plans in parallel, I see these differences:

1. seq scan on entities1  is faster than index scan on entities2, but the seq scan has to hashaggregate resulting in a more expensive subplan. 
   Ok, without statistics being collected, maybe the seq scan is more efficient than a non updated index scan.
2. the hashaggregate on entities1 says: rows = 200, which is the default estimated value. 
   Again maybe it's legit because no statistics are collected
3. the sort methods. When forced to parallel, entities2 has to perform an external merge sort on disk, caused by the size of the data (175MB on both workers). Entities1 has practically no load (50KB on both workers), and the plan chose to perform a quicksort.

Both queries return the same result, I don't understand the need of sort, but less than that, I don't understand why the ANALYZE command impact so bad on performances.

What I am missing?

Let me know if I omitted some details

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you replace: extract(year ...) with date_trunc('year', otherfield) and run the explain analyze

Comment: I'm not convinced that the bad performances are caused by the ANALYSE command. I don't know why the planner votes for seq scan on one side and index scan on the other, but as there is no `WHERE` clause in your query, the full table must be scanned, and in this case, the seq scan may be faster than the index scan : *"For a query that requires scanning a large fraction of the table, an explicit sort is likely to be faster than using an index because it requires less disk I/O due to following a sequential access pattern. Indexes are more useful when only a few rows need be fetched"*

Comment: @mshabou

interesting, I obtain the same plan from the 2 tables, but without parallelism. Relevant parts:
single copy: true
HashAggregate  rows=16836383
Group Key: date_trunc('year'::text, ""otherfield"")"
Planned Partitions: 8"
Worker 0:  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 98329kB"
Index Only Scan using ix .....
Execution Time: 7016.079 ms

Comment: @Edouard yes I have the same thought about the seq scan, it makes sense. The statement about the ANALYSE is because I tried to only VACUUM, then to only REINDEX, then to only ANALYZE, and the differences shows in the last command

Comment: What are your nondefault server settings?

Comment: What are the contents of pg_stats for these tables?

Comment: entities1 should get vacuumed and analyzed automatically.  If you wait for those to finish, does it then join entities2 in the bad plan?

Comment: @jjanes 1) fresh install, I just set parallel_setup_cost and parallel_tuple_cost for testing, but it's reported in my post.  2) when created fresh, pg_stats for entities1 shows empty recordset. For entities2 I have data. 3) yes, a day has passed and entities1 now has been vacuumed and analyzed, and has a "bad" plan.

Comment: Do your cloned tables have indexes?

Comment: @O.Jones yes, same as the initial one. I could have chosen a more covering index but that is not the only query I will run

Comment: I can't reproduce those plans with the default planner settings, so it is hard to figure out what might be going on.  What are the actual contents of pg_stats for these rows?  In particular, n_distinct and correlation?

Comment: @jjanes I'm sorry maybe when I set up parallel_setup_cost=100000 and parallel_tuple_cost = 0.001 for testing, I also forced the planner to go parallel with force_parallel_mode = on. n_distinct values are: id=-1, somefield=27, otherfield=-0.86. correlation values are: id=0.65, somefield=0.55, otherfield=0.65

Comment: @jjanes but my concern isn't about parallelism, because all the time loss is in the sort function. Maybe, if I wanted the rows in some order becomes mandatory analyzing the tables. But still I can't explain to myself this huge difference in this specific problem